# Replace many values in txt file

Tags: replace, indexing, notepad++

I have file with thousand records!

I want to remove one line having some criteria, its so simple if its just like that, but the line is having at least three following line (also need to be deleted).

First step :

Example

I want to remove all bob's record, sometime 3 or more :

```
1   my name is **bob**
2   **bob** is 30 yrs old
3   **bob** is smart
4   my name is Ann
5   my name is **bob**
6   **bob** is 30 yrs old
7   **bob** is smart
8   **bob** having headache.
```

- I want to remove bob's lines, so I will remove line 1,2 and 3.
- I need Ann line (4)
- I want to remove bob's lines, so I want to remove line 5,6,7 and 8.

Second step:

- (******) any common chr.
- replace bob to (*****)
- replace David to (*****)
- ......
- ....
- ..

  ## - .

Example 2

- 10 Name bob
- 20 age 40
- 30 Male
- 10 Name David
- 20 age 13
- 30 Male
- 10 Name Ann
- 20 age 20
- 30 Male
- 40 USA

I want to delete bob and Ann , with all related records!
There is nothing common between them, so I have to change (bob and Ann) to (chr) so I can easy deal with. I want to have the values (new and old) in txt file!

Any idea on this?

Comment: Not a notepad++ job I think...

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I used notepad++ to bookmark the line I need to delete but I have to delete 3 related follow lines.

Comment: how about a Python script? I dont think any software could do such special requirements...

Comment: Thanks, I already tried it but I am not familiar with it!

Comment: The example can be solved by simply removing any line containing `bob`, so the purpose of the "at least three following" and "sometime 3 or more" phrases is not clear. Can these phrases be ignored or can a better example be provided?

Comment: Thanks Adrian I will update a second example.

Comment: The updated examples are not clear. What defines the start and the end of a record? Does each record start with a "Name" line? What are the numbers at the start of each line and do names always start with a "10"? What is the significance (if any) of the blank lines?

Answer (score 0):

In replace box:

```
search what: ^.*\bbob\b.*\r\n
replace with: <Nothing>
```

with `Regular expression` checked and `dot includes newline` NOT checked

Click on `Replace all`

You could also use:

```
search what: ^.*\bbob\b.*\R
```

Comment: This is true, but want to replace around 3000 record.

Comment: @user3145937: Sorry, I don't get you. This is working for any amount of records.

Comment: yes you are right, but I need to change 3000 different names to a common chr!

Comment: @user3145937 same here. I can't understand what you want exactly. What does "common chr" mean? Please try to rephrase again your question!

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++, go to `Search` > `Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   ^.*\b[Bb]ob\b.*$
   ```
2. Replace with:

   ```
   <leave empty>
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression"
4. Then press "Replace All"

This will convert your list:

```
1   my name is **bob**
2   **bob** is 30 yrs old
3   **bob** is smart
4   my name is Ann
5   my name is **bob**
6   **bob** is 30 yrs old
7   **bob** is smart
8   **bob** having headache.
```

To:

```
4 my name is Ann
```

You can test it online at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/wC4kV0).

Comment: Thanks, but this is an example, I have many to replace and the main scope to have them all with common character so I can remove them all in one shot!